# Service worker doesn't return file from cache

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to cache a single page webapp with a service worker. It should get all it's files from the cache and update that cache only when a new service worker-version is published.

With a precache function i'm writing some files to the cache as follows:

```
function precache() {
return caches.open(CACHE).then(function(cache) {
    return cache.addAll([
        'index.html',
        'js/script.js',
        'img/bg.png',
        'img/logo.svg',
        ...
    ]);
});
}
```

(I've tried to cache with and without "/" before the paths, and even with absolute paths. Makes no difference)

In Chrome's Cache Storage, the content of all those files is exactly as it should be. But when I try to serve the files from cache on reload of the page, none of the requests match with the cache, they all get rejected, even when I'm still online.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(evt) {
    evt.respondWith(
        caches.match(evt.request).then(function(response) {
            if(response){
                return response;
            } else {
                reject('no result');
            }
        }).catch(function(){
            if(evt.request.url == 'https://myurl.com'){
                return caches.match('/index.html');
            }
        });
    )
});
```

The index.html from the catch-function gets served correctly, and in turn requests the other files, like /js/script.js. Those request show up like this in the console:

> Request { method: 'GET', url: 'https://myurl.com/js/script.js', ... referrer: 'https://myurl.com' }

But they do not return a response, only a notice like this shows:

> The FetchEvent for "https://myurl.com/js/script.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().

Am I missing something here?

Comment: from the error - there is a type mismatch... ie u have objs in the cache but they r of wrong type -- not =Response

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match `.match` doesn't return a failed promise. If there is not a match it resolves to `undefined`. You can probably just move your `catch` to the `then` block with `if (!response && url == 'https://myurl.com') and then `else return response`

Comment: @Rajit thank you for pointing me to that documentation! The catch statement didn't give me more information, but the docs pointed me to the options argument for the match-statement, which solved the problem. I've answered my question for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the link from Rajit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match I've found that the `caches.match()` function accepts an options-object.

I've updated that line in my service worker to

```
caches.match(evt.request,{cacheName:CACHE,ignoreVary:true}).then(function(response) {
```

so it includes the cache-name and an ignores VARY header matching, and now it returns the correct files.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it seems to have been solved by using the  `ignoreVary:true` parameter.  The documentation explicitly states that the  `cacheName` parameter is ignored by `Cache.match()`

Answer (score 0):

Important note is to add all possible url versions, with, without trailing slash, because even when autocompleted, it seems to bee seen as two different things. So, for example, if you had a pwa in `domain/folder/`,

calling `domain/folder/` online and caching wont make `domain/folder` work offline (in some cases) unless you previously accessed the later online as well.

#### Solution:

when adding via caches.addAll or similar, **add both**

`'/folder/'`

AND

`'/folder'`.

What never did a thing for me on the other hand, was *ignoreVary*  .